# wxPython MacOS X Lion full screen mode

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, osx-lion

I am making a wxPython application that needs to work in full screen. I want to use the new full screen mode that came in OS X Lion. How can I make the full screen icon appear on the top right corner?

Comment: What have you tried? A quick Google search for "wxpython full screen" has revealed several different options.

Comment: He specifically wants to use Lion's new full-screen API. wxWidgets doesn't have this functionality yet.

Comment: @nneonneo That's as may be but the question as written doesn't show any independent research effort, which is against community guidelines.

Comment: I wouldn't have known how to do it either...this is a new feature of OS X, and not a lot of GUI frameworks aside from Apple's own support it yet.

Answer (score 2):

Until [bug #14357](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/14357) is fixed, there's no *direct* way to do this using only wxPython functions that I know of.

However, you can bypass wxWidgets and access the Cocoa APIs directly to do what you need. Note that you *must* be using the wxMac/Cocoa bindings (wxPython 2.9 or above).

This is the code necessary to make a frame full-screen capable:

```
# from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328143/getting-pyobjc-object-from-integer-id
import ctypes, objc
_objc = ctypes.PyDLL(objc._objc.__file__)

# PyObject *PyObjCObject_New(id objc_object, int flags, int retain)
_objc.PyObjCObject_New.restype = ctypes.py_object
_objc.PyObjCObject_New.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]

def objc_object(id):
    return _objc.PyObjCObject_New(id, 0, 1)

def SetFullScreenCapable(frame):
    frameobj = objc_object(frame.GetHandle())

    NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary = 1<<7
    window = frameobj.window()
    newBehavior = window.collectionBehavior() | NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary
    window.setCollectionBehavior_(newBehavior)
```

And here's a short test app that demonstrates it:

```
import wxversion
wxversion.select('2-osx_cocoa') # require Cocoa version of wxWidgets
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
        wx.Button(self, label="Hello!") # test button to demonstrate full-screen resizing
        SetFullScreenCapable(self)

    def OnClose(self, event):
        exit()

app = wx.App()
frame = Frame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: When using your above code on MountainLion 10.8.2 with python 2.7.2 I get a AttributeError: 'NSHIObject' object has no attribute 'window' the whole code and error is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068923/wxpython-mac-os-x-fullscreen-work-around-error#comment19955401_14068923 I suspect I am missing something because I can't see why the code would produce the error (well why it wouldn't have a window attribute)

Comment: I have since answered the question it has to do with Carbon or Cocoa as the backend, see the question's answer for more information.