# Getting pyobjc object from integer id

Tags: python, wxpython, pyobjc

Is there a way to get a PyObjC proxy object for an Objective-C object, given only its `id` as an integer? Can it be done without an extension module?

In my case, I'm trying to get a Cocoa proxy object from the return value of `wx.Frame.GetHandle` (using wxMac with Cocoa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one solution I did find relies on `ctypes` to create an `objc_object` object from the `id`:

```
import ctypes, objc
_objc = ctypes.PyDLL(objc._objc.__file__)

# PyObject *PyObjCObject_New(id objc_object, int flags, int retain)
_objc.PyObjCObject_New.restype = ctypes.py_object
_objc.PyObjCObject_New.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int]

def objc_object(id):
    return _objc.PyObjCObject_New(id, 0, 1)
```

An example of its use to print a `wx.Frame`:

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, pos=(150,150), size=(350,200))

        m_print = wx.Button(self, label="Print")
        m_print.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPrint)

    def OnPrint(self, event):
        topobj = objc_object(top.GetHandle())
        topobj.print_(None)

app = wx.App()
top = Frame(title="ObjC Test")
top.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

It's a little nasty since it uses `ctypes`. If there's a `pyobjc` API function I overlooked or some other neater way to do it, I'd surely be interested.

Comment: Yikes. This should work, but this is very fragile: future versions of PyObjC might not have a "PyObjCObject_New" function in the _objc extension.

Answer (score 1):

In PyObjC 2.5 you can use this:

```
import objc
objc.objc_object(ctypes_void_p=some_object_id)
```

There is no public API for doing this in earlier versions of PyObjC.