# OS X fullscreen in wxWidgets 3.0

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, wxwidgets

I contribute to a cross-platform application which is built using wxWidgets stable version - 3.0.2.

I would like to enable the app to use the native fullscreen system on OS X Lion and above. This feature is implemented in current development versions of wxWidgets, but not in 3.0.2.

I understand that it should be possible to call the native Cocoa API from within the wxWidgets app to enable fullscreen mode, but I can't work out how to do so and can't find any information online.

How can I directly access the NSWindow class from my wxWidgets C++ code?

For reference, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327641/wxpython-macos-x-lion-full-screen-mode) asks how to do the same with wxPython, and gets an answer - but python is different enough from C++ that I can't work out how I would do it in standard wxWidgets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wxWindow::MacGetTopLevelWindowRef()` to get the `NSWindow`. See [this commit](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/6451d231588987dc9e08726d64fe254bdfa9bee5) for what you can do with it afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I had also found GetWXWindow(), which also seems to return the NSWindow. But, I haven't been able to work out what to do to it, though I've seen the code you linked to. Do I really need to add a .mm (Objective C) file to the app? Isn't there a way to call the required methods directly from my C++ code, like they have from Python in the answer I linked to? Whenever I try doing anything with the NSWindow I get an error: member access into incomplete type 'struct NSWindow'. But I can't work out what header I would include to avoid that. I'm rather inexperienced with C++ and wxWidgets...

Comment: You can't avoid using Objective-C. And I think you really need to use `MacGetTopLevelWindowRef()` to get the right `NSWindow`.

Comment: Hmm. Ok. So the question becomes, how do I include the necessary Objective C from my C++ app, and how do I only do it on OS X. I shall do some more research down that line.